# IE11 iframe memory leak with reactjs and antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, iframe, memory-leaks

I got memory leak problem with IE11. When I adding and remove child iframe, the memory goes up for 50M after removing the child iframe in production mode.

And I found, in development mode, when I render a antd Button in iframe, the memory leak problem is bigger. And When I render a div instead of the antd Button, the memory leak problem almost gone.

```
// only a div
<Route path="/expenseclaim" component={() => (<div>1</div>)} />

// with antd Button
<Route path="/expenseclaim" component={() => (<Button>1</Button>)} />
```

And I use these code to clear iframe:

```
  removeIframe = () => {
      const isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
      if (!isIE11) {
          return;
      }
      var _i = document.getElementById('taskIframe');
      if (!_i) {
          return;
      }

      try {
          _i.src = 'about:blank';
          _i.contentWindow.document.write('');
          _i.contentWindow.document.clear && _i.contentWindow.document.clear();
          _i.contentWindow.close();
          _i.remove();
          console.log('done');
      } catch (e) {
          console.log('removeIframe error');
      }
      if (typeof window.CollectGarbage === 'function') {
          window.CollectGarbage();
      }
  }
```

Any ideas? Thanks. :)

Here is the memory status I record after I did create and remove iframe three times in development mode:

[image: description]

I should learn to find the memory leak part.

Find memory leaks with Chrome Dev Tools:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrPa0mEk4Pw

I found there's no problem with chrome (version78):
[image]

A minimal demo to reproduce the problem:

```
// IframeTest
import React from 'react'
import { Table, Checkbox, Button } from 'antd';
import IframeContainer from './IframeContainer'
export default class IframeTest extends React.Component {
  state = {
      showIframe: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
  }
  switchIframe = () => {
      this.setState({ showIframe: !this.state.showIframe })
  }

  render() {
    const { showIframe }  = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
            <Button onClick={this.switchIframe}>switch iframe</Button>
            { showIframe && <IframeContainer ></IframeContainer>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

IframeContainer

```
import React from 'react'


export default class IframeContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
  };

  componentDidMount() {
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
      console.log('un')
  }

  render() {

    let host = 'http://192.168.64.68:3001/'
    host = 'https://ant.design/components/button-cn/'
    const iframeSrc = `${host}`
    return (
      <React.Fragment>

            { <iframe src={iframeSrc}></iframe>}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of OS version and IE browser version (detail version) are you using? You could refer to these links ([thread](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3120078/memory-leak-after-you-append-and-remove-iframe-elements-in-internet-ex) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityBulletins/2016/ms16-001?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) and try to install the most recent cumulative security update for Internet Explorer

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT IE version: 11.1198.14393.0   win10

Comment: I have tried to create a similar sample based on your code, but can't reproduce the problem? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, please refer to [this article](https://www.bryntum.com/blog/debugging-memory-leaks-in-web-applications-using-iframes/) and  check your code whether you will access the elements in the iframe and attach event? And check the JavaScript reference version, perhaps the issue is related to the jquery version, try to use the latest version of JQuery version.

Comment: OK, I will try to make a minimal demo. Thanks.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Please check out the demo codes above if you got some time. Thanks very much.

Comment: I have tested your code on my side, I think perhaps the issue is related to the iframe src value, when I test it using the ant web site, the memory increase almost 80M after click the switch Iframe button, and even I add a remove Iframe button, it seems that the memory not dropped after clicking it. But after change the Iframe src value to "let  host = 'https://www.bing.com/'", the problem has almost gone. You could check it. Besides, please check your code, you want to remove the Iframe according the ID property, don't forget to add id property on the Iframe tag.